# How to create a filter on service bus topic subscription on message property?

Tags: azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have one topic `DemoTopic` and having 2 subscriptions 'sub1' and `sub2`

my message payload is like this

```
{
   "data": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "a",
                "pid": "p1"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "b",
                "pid": "p2"
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "name": "c",
                "pid": "p3"
            }
            ]
}
```

if pid value is `p1 and p2` then send messsage to `sub1`

how to create a filter for this using p1 and p2 value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscriptions can only filter messages on some system properties and user/custom properties (aka headers). If your message contains the data required for filtering, you should promote those property values to the headers when dispatching messages.